# phpmailer / sendmail returning error "Connection reset by peer"

Tags: email, xampp, phpmailer, windows-7-x64, sendmail.exe

I'm trying to run phpmailer/sendmail from localhost with a gmail account. I use XAMPP.

I use the template from http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-registration-form.html

I try since few weeks now but still did not manage to make it work.
Do you have an idea from the following logs ?

I'm a beginner so feel free to ask me if you need further data.
Thanks

crash.txt

```
date/time         : 2016-01-22, 12:23:46, 747ms
computer name     : **
user name         : SYSTEM <admin>
registered owner  : Microsoft / Microsoft
operating system  : Windows XP Media Center x64 Service Pack 3 build 2600 (in fact this is a compatibility as admin. My real version is Win7 x64
system language   : English
system up time    : 12 days 2 hours
program up time   : 21 seconds
processors        : 8x Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2670QM CPU @ 2.20GHz
physical memory   : 2936/8044 MB (free/total)
free disk space   : (C:) 165.48 GB
display mode      : 1024x768, 32 bit
process id        : $6d20
allocated memory  : 17.00 MB
command line      : "C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe" -t
executable        : sendmail.exe
exec. date/time   : 2012-04-16 18:30
compiled with     : Delphi 2006/07
madExcept version : 3.0l
callstack crc     : $1d5da2f6, $426ead6b, $426ead6b
exception number  : 1
exception class   : EIdSocketError
exception message : Socket Error # 10054 Connection reset by peer.
```

debug.log

```
16/01/22 12:23:25 ** --- MESSAGE BEGIN ---
16/01/22 12:23:25 ** To:  email <email@gmail.com>
16/01/22 12:23:25 ** Subject: Your registration with user11.com
16/01/22 12:23:25 ** Date: Fri, 22 Jan 2016 12:23:25 +0100
16/01/22 12:23:25 ** Return-Path: nobody@localhost
16/01/22 12:23:25 ** From: Root User <nobody@localhost>
16/01/22 12:23:25 ** Message-ID: <f7667d2c9812101585751b11c67b9c84@localhost>
16/01/22 12:23:25 ** X-Priority: 3
16/01/22 12:23:25 ** X-Mailer: PHPMailer (phpmailer.sourceforge.net) [version 2.0.4]
16/01/22 12:23:25 ** MIME-Version: 1.0
16/01/22 12:23:25 ** Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
16/01/22 12:23:25 ** Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
16/01/22 12:23:25 ** 
16/01/22 12:23:25 ** Hello email 
16/01/22 12:23:25 ** 
16/01/22 12:23:25 ** Thanks for your registration with user11.com
16/01/22 12:23:25 ** Please click the link below to confirm your registration.
16/01/22 12:23:25 ** http://localhost/project_webapp/registration_login_forms/confirmreg.php?code=a3c8d5758bdcec87a8ac4dfe8c85fa1d
16/01/22 12:23:25 ** 
16/01/22 12:23:25 ** Regards,
16/01/22 12:23:25 ** Webmaster
16/01/22 12:23:25 ** user11.com
16/01/22 12:23:25 ** 
16/01/22 12:23:25 ** --- MESSAGE END ---
16/01/22 12:23:25 ** Connecting to smtp.gmail.com:587
16/01/22 12:23:46 ** Disconnected.
16/01/22 12:23:46 ** Disconnected.
16/01/22 12:23:46 ** Disconnected.
16/01/22 12:23:46 ** Socket Error # 10054<EOL>Connection reset by peer.
```

sendmail.ini:

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
smtp_ssl=ssl
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=email@gmail.com
auth_password=*******
pop3_server=
pop3_username=
pop3_password=
force_sender=email@gmail.com
force_recipient=
hostname=smtp.gmail.com
```

php.ini

```
[mail function]
 smtp=smtp.gmail.com
 smtp_port = 587

; For Win32 only.
 sendmail_from = email@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
mail.add_x_header=Off
```

Comment: PHPMailer 2.0.4 is many, many years out of date. I'm amazed it works at all! [Get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and base your code on the examples provided.

Comment: Indeed. It was a good start. I downloaded the latest version and it works perfectly. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloading the latest version was the solution! I simply put the smtp port to 587 for using with gmail.(Solution suggested by Synchro ;)

Working with an up-to-date version is indeed a good start.